# How to get attributes of sub records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm Working on a project with a model structure as follows:

```
Person has many Pets has many collars has a colour
```

I have an active record of people, and I'd like to get all of the collars of those peoples pets, where colour = 'Blue', but I'm not sure how to do this. I originally had `Collar.Where(colour: 'blue')`, but I then realised they had to be scoped by those people.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: so do you want persons collection?

Comment: I want collars of the pets of the persons, which have a colour blue

Comment: of which persons?

Comment: I have a list of person records which are a sub set of all the persons in the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get a list of persons, whose pets collars colour is blue:

```
Person.joins(pets: :collars)
      .where(collars: { colour: 'blue' })
      .group('persons.id')
```

If you want to get a collection of collars of pets of specific persons (substitute `ids` with actual ids of the persons):

```
Collar.joins(pet: :person)
      .where(collars: { colour: 'blue' }, persons: { id: ids })
      .group('collars.id')
```

In the last query I assumed, that `Collar belongs_to :pet` and `Pet belongs_to :person`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the models as follows:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pets
  has_many :collars, through: :pets
end

class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :collars
end

class Collar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pet
end
```

To get blue collars of a given person:

```
person.collars.where(color: 'blue')
```

To get blue collars of a given people:

```
Collar.
  joins(pet: :person).
  where(color: 'blue').
  where(people: { id: people.map(&:id) })
```

Comment: and this is different from already given answer exactly how...? Or is `people` in your answer instead of `persons` in mine (which probably is right) make it worth a whole new answer? :)

Comment: Not many new people know about `has_many through`. If you have a `person`,  acquiring related `collars` in one step without `joins` is quite useful.

Comment: not that I am trying to be a badass, but not speaking of the fact, that `has_many though` is not even distantly related to the question, how is your answer teaches those, who do not know about it? :) P.S. Only after I wrote this comment (and reread yours) I realized, that first part of the answer actually aims to show the benefits of hmt. I suggest to reword to make it more explicit..

Comment: You can disagree, but if you take a look into what I wrote - my main message is that I did not get from the first sight on your answer, that it aims to show the benefits of `has_many through`. I doubt many people would get it. Instead of responding to it (or even better, reword these few sentences of your answer) you only react to badass part.

Comment: You can flag my comment if you deem it rude - it's along the rules, no offences taken. I explained myself in that exact comment and do not see anything offensive/rude/outlaw (except, maybe, for the badass word itself). Sorry, if you do - was not my intention.

Comment: No offense taken. I gave an honest answer to your original comment ignoring the whole `make it worth a whole new answer` sarcasm. The question is quite ambivalent, it is not clear if he wants to get collars associated with a single person or multiple people. If it is the former, getting collars without `joins` is idiomatic. When I am reading a SO answer I find it useful when there are many ways to solve the same problem.